# Limit what UITextField displays as user is typing based on characters inputted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I was wondering if it is possible to limit the what `UITextField` displays based on the characters entered by an user as *they are typing*. For example, I would like to exclude the character "!" from being displayed in the `UITextField`, so when a user enters "Nice!", what she sees in the textfield is just "Nice", with the blinker next to "e".

I have attempted to use `shoudChangeCharactersInRange` and experimented with something basic like turning all the words entered into lower case, but has not gotten it to work. What would be the best way to approach this, especially if I want to keep out some letters or character altogether? Thanks

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self updateTextLabelsWithText: newString.lowercaseString];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: FYI - please stop using the iPhone tag for all of your questions. It almost never applies.

Comment: Done - I'll remove them from the previous questions too.

Comment: What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: The code applied (which changes everything to lowercaseString) doesn't appear to work for what text is displayed in the `UITextField`. I can enter "HELLO" and it still stay as "HELLO" and not as "hello" as intended.

Comment: You are going to need to show us the `updateTextLabelsWithText:` method.

Comment: Thanks for checking. `updateTextLabelsWithText` updates a different `UILabel`, which works fine with the `lowercaseString` method, but what I am really after is preventing a non-sanctioned character from even being "entered" so to speak (i.e. it doesn't show up in the `UITextField` and the blinker stays on with the previous character entered)

Comment: You're making no effort to filter any characters. Look at the related questions to yours or do some searching. There is are many examples of how to validate input into a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated Answer

OK, could you try this version please, see if it handles the extra pasting of string with invalid characters?

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    BOOL shouldReplace = YES;

    NSRange invalidCharRange = [string rangeOfString:@"!"];

    if(invalidCharRange.length > 0)
    {
        shouldReplace = NO;

        NSString *cleanedString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@""];

        NSString *completeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", textField.text, cleanedString];

        textField.text = completeString;
    }
    else
    {
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@""];
    }

    if([string isEqualToString:@"!"])
    {
        shouldReplace = NO;
    }

    return shouldReplace;
}
```

### Original Answer

Just set NO if the replacement string is "!":

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    BOOL shouldReplace = YES;

    if([string isEqualToString:@"!"])
    {
        shouldReplace = NO;
    }

    return shouldReplace;
}
```

Comment: It's best to limit your code to just the relevant part. No need for the `viewDidLoad` and `didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods in the answer.

Comment: Also, this answer will fail if the user pastes in text that is more than one character and one of the pasted characters is an undesired character.

Comment: This did the trick - thank you! Great thought about pasting @rmaddy, this is a `UITextField` where its very unlikely that pasting will occur, but I'll set up some safeguard.

Comment: I've updated the answer with handling of pasting words containing invalid characters too, see if that works for you @daspianist. Although if your requirements change, like you want to filter @ characters in addition to ! characters, then you'd probably need a more robust checking function that recursively checks every invalid character and replace them in the string recursively before returning it.

Comment: Terrific - this works great now, even for pasted strings. Thanks a lot @Zhang!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *previousString_ = textField.text;
    NSString *upperCased_ = [string uppercaseString];
    previousString_ = [previousString_ stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:upperCased_];
    [textField setText:previousString_];

    return NO;
}
```

This code will change lower input string to upper cased

Comment: Thank you - this was very helpful in pointing me to the right direction.